# How to catch UrlFetchApp.fetch exception

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

Is there any way to catch the exception from `UrlFetchApp.fetch`?

I thought I can use `response.getResponseCode()` to check the response code, but I'm not able to, for e.g when there is 404 error, the script not continue and just stop at `UrlFetchApp.fetch`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Edit**: This parameter is now [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch%28String,Object%29).

You can use the undocumented advanced option "muteHttpExceptions" to disable exceptions when a non-200 status code is returned, and then inspect the status code of the response. More information and an example is available on [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1202#c2).

Answer (score 33):

The trick is passing the `muteHttpExceptions` param of [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)).

Here an example (untested):

```
var payload = {"value": "key"}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
            url,
            {
              method: "PUT",
              contentType: "application/json",
              payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
              muteHttpExceptions: true,
            }
          );
var responseCode = response.getResponseCode()
var responseBody = response.getContentText()

if (responseCode === 200) {
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody)
  // ...
} else {
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s", responseCode, responseBody))
  // ...
}
```

For some reason if the URL is not available (e.g. the service you're trying to use is down) it still looks like is throwing an error so you may still need to use a `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you use try catch and handle the error in catch block

```
try{
    //Your original code, UrlFetch etc
  }
  catch(e){
    // Logger.log(e);
    //Handle error e here 
    // Parse e to get the response code
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
Is it possible to find out what is the response code when there is exception?

Comment: You will get an error string in e which you can parse to get the error code.

Comment: But parsing `e` is not that straight forward, since UrlFetchApp wraps the response inside a text message.. I won't suggest this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually parse the caught error, but it's not recommended. When catching the exception (that is being thrown in case `muteHttpExceptions` is turned off), the error object would be in the following format:

```
{
   "message": "Request failed for ___ returned code___. Truncated server response: {___SERVER_RESPONSE_OBJECT___} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)",
   "name": "Exception",
   "fileName": "___FILE_NAME___",
   "lineNumber": ___LINE_NUMBER___,
   "stack": "___STACK_DETAILS___"
}
```

If you for some reason prefer not using `muteHttpExceptions`, you could catch the exception `e`, look at `e.message`, substring the text between "Truncated server response: " and " (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)", JSON.parse() it, and the returned object would be the error returned from the api call.

I wouldn't suggest it over `muteHttpExceptions`, just wanted to show the best way to get the error object this way.

Anyways, try-catch your `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call to make sure you catch the unhandled exceptions, like 404.